# How do I get a new value from an editable combo box?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am trying to add a value to an editable combo box called nameComboBox that I created in the Scene Builder.

I populate the combo box with this code:

```
  private ObservableList<String> getNames()
  {
      return (FXCollections.observableArrayList("Freddy","Kerstin"));
  }

..

nameComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(getNames());
```

I have a Save button defined form the Scene Builder. The code looks like this:

```
@FXML
  private void handleSaveBtn()
  {
     System.out.println("The new name  is " + nameComboBox.getValue());
  }
```

When the scene is displayed,  the combo boxes editable field is displayed empty with the two names hidden in the list underneath the empty field, which is what I want to happen.

If then type "Rusty" in the empty field and click a save button all that happens is that the println statement returns
"The new name is null".

If I wanted to do something with the new value, like validate it or store it in a database, how do I get the value that I entered in the editable field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead of `.getValue()` :

```
nameComboBox.getEditor().getText()
```

This returns the value of the `textProperty` of the `TextField` (`.getEditor()`) of the editable `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  nameComboBox.setItems(getNames());
   nameComboBox.setValue("Freddy");
```